# How to use Panels for styling/layout Ubercart 3 Product Kits?

Tags: ubercart, panels

I'm using Panels to build a layout for Produck Kit in Ubercart 3 but I can't show the product links that appear in the normal product kit, Is there something I'm missing? I have tried adding "Node Links", "Node Content", "Attached files" but no luck. Please help. Thanks